# URL generates blank screen when trying signed URL's in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying a small example on signed URLs in Laravel here's is web.php

```
<?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 use App\Http\Controllers\InvitationController;
    
 Route::get('/discount',function(){
    return 'some_discount_code_here';
 })->name('discountCode')->middleware('signed');

 Route::get('/generate-signature','App\Http\Controllers\InvitationController@discount');
```

and here is InvitationController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class InvitationController extends Controller
{ 
    public function discount(){
        URL::signedRoute('discountCode');
    }
}
```

the problem is when I visit /generate-signature from my web browser it only shows blank screen , no error or 403 invalid signature only blank screen , I don't see the regenerated /discount link with the signature added  .

Note : I have checked Kernel.php and signed exists in $routeMiddleware array and the servers are up and running .

Comment: Have you checked the PHP error log?

Comment: @Brian No , I don't know how to do that .

Comment: Why would it show anything? You don't return anything from your controller method.